# How can I display the content in the red box at the bottom corner of the card using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBxYh.png)

I've been trying to move this row to the bottom of the container for hours now, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex align-items-center vstack">

        <div class="myCard gradient-day shadow px-3 pt-5 m-5 rounded">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1 class="" id="day-of-week">Tuesday</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h4 class="" id="todays-date">Jan 2nd 2023</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center g-3">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <h5><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3 class="" id="city-name">City Name</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-cols-1">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1 class="" id="temperature">51 °F</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h4 class="" id="weather">Sunny</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
            <form action="" id="searchForm">
                <div class="mx-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search for city" name="query" autofocus>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>
```

I've tried using justify-self-end and align-self-end on the row which hasn't worked. I think the issue has something to do with the .vstack class. I found that I could move the container to the center of the viewport using a combination of .d-flex, .align-items-center, and .vstack. If there's a better way to do it, I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Please read this - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#with-align-items

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.myCard`'s container and `margin-top: auto` to the last-row. For increasing the specificity of last-row styles, I've selected that row by using the `.myCard` class.

```css
.myCard .container {
  min-height: 400px;
  padding-inline: 2em;
  padding-block: 1em;
  width: max-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myCard .myCard__last-row {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex align-items-center vstack">
  <div class="myCard gradient-day shadow px-3 pt-5 m-5 rounded">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="" id="day-of-week">Tuesday</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h4 class="" id="todays-date">Jan 2nd 2023</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center g-3">
        <div class="col-1">
          <h5><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h3 class="" id="city-name">City Name</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 myCard__last-row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="" id="temperature">51 °F</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h4 class="" id="weather">Sunny</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="" id="searchForm">
      <div class="mx-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search for city" name="query" autofocus>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```